# Is the aesthetics tag suitable for SO?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, burninate-request

Though I can see how programming questions might involve UI/UX design, is [aesthetics](/questions/tagged/aesthetics) really suitable for StackOverflow given that these questions are likely to be more subjective?

Is it time to burninate the tag on the (currently) 42 questions that use it?

Comment: There appears to be an R function/package/extension/thingy called "aes" which is short for aesthetics (http://docs.ggplot2.org/0.9.3/aes.html). If that thing's worth a tag, there might be some rework to do (i.e. just getting rid of the tag might be problematic.)

Comment: If the tag is being misused frequently and the aesthetics package is unique to R, maybe renaming the tag to `r-aesthetics` to avoid confusion?

Comment: It might help if someone familiar with the package updated the tag wiki as well.

Comment: Hmm, there's also the [appearance](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/appearance) tag. No tag summary and it doesn't seem to apply primarily to a single language...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An examination of the first few answers in that tag seems to indicate that 'aesthetics' are specific elements related to plotting functionality in the R language. Those questions appear to be valid, on-topic and are using the tag correctly.

If there are subjective questions relating to a more general concept of aesthetics, they may be candidates for closure, but I think this tag is useful and should remain.

Comment: Even if tag reverse engineering shows its meaning, the lack of tag wiki makes it misleading, so the OP's question is fully reasonable.